# Word2Vec : Interpretation of Subtraction or addition of vectors

Tags: machine-learning, text-mining, word2vec

I am curious, what does subtracting vectors, as in [man – woman] do in regards to Google's word2vec calculation of analogy ? Is this a measure of how different the two vectors are? So is

man – woman (approx.)= king – queen

saying the difference between man and woman is (approximately) the same as the difference between king and queen?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, that's my understanding of their interpretation; that's the reasoning behind why you'd expect (as observed) that `[man] - [woman] + [king] ≈ [queen]`, or `[Paris] - [France] + [China] ≈ [Beijing]`.

The idea is perhaps that vectors are approximately sums of their semantic components, so that `[king]` includes a "male" component as well as "ruler", "person", and whatever else, and `[queen]` has basically the same set of components except it has "female" instead of "male". `[man] - [woman]` would then end up at `["male"] - ["female"]`, so adding it to `[king]` would just swap the "male" concept for "female".

I kind of doubt there's a more complete understanding of it than that, though I'm not familiar with all of the literature on the subject and someone may have studied it in more detail.

Comment: So [vector a] - [vector b] is to be thought of (generally, not just in this case) as a measure of how different the vectors are from each other?

Comment: @B_Miner Not sure what you mean by that. It's the difference between the two vectors, by definition; if it has large norm, the two vectors can be thought of as very different. But in this case the direction of the difference is important as well as just the length of "how different" they are.

Comment: I was trying to think of intuitively why subtracting the two vectors would make sense and if [a-b] describes how different they were. I think I see your point, a large norm means a large "difference" but what matters is the entire resulting difference vector.

Answer (score 3):

Actually there has been some recent theoretical advances in understanding how the addition/subtraction of vectors works. See here:

http://andyljones.tumblr.com/post/111299309808/why-word2vec-works
http://arxiv.org/abs/1502.03520

I would give a summary here - but I don't think I could do any better than Andy in his blog!

Comment: Thanks for the reference; I'm glad someone's looking into this rigorously. The blog post is a good description and the paper is now high on my to-read list.

Comment: FWIW the author of that blog post is [@AndyJones](http://stats.stackexchange.com/users/62206/andy-jones), though I don't think that will notify him....

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! As it stands this is probably better suited to be a comment than an answer - a summary (which needn't be a long one) of what a reader might expect to find if they follow either link would be very helpful. (Also full references with title, author, &c.)